# Troubles with boost::phoenix::function

Tags: c++, boost, lazy-evaluation, boost-phoenix

Using [boost::phoenix::function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/phoenix/doc/html/phoenix/modules/function/adapting_functions.html) I encountered some problems. As far as I know this lazy function requiries functor as its template parameter. I have to define a functor class/structure and then pass it as a template parameter for instantiation. But it's too long and redundant. Can I use some other callable type for `phoenix::function` creation (function reference/pointer etc.)? I tried `lambdas`:

```
 const auto foo = [] { cout <<"Test"; }
 const boost::phoenix::function<decltype(foo)> lazy;
```

but call to `lazy()` didn't compile. So the question are there any alternatives instead of functor classes for fast one-line `phoenix::function` creation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the type of `foo` isn't default constructible, `lazy` needs an initializer:

```
boost::phoenix::function<decltype(foo)> lazy { foo };
```

Comment: @AlexanderKaraberov [Of course my example does compile](http://liveworkspace.org/code/f75905c9b9c0ca5b5707a7ecbd092d27). You can try `boost::phoenix::function<decltype(foo)> lazy(foo);` in case your compiler has trouble with brace-initialization.